# Как сделать фоновый таймер?

Tags: javascript

Хочу установить фоновый таймер на сайте, например, на 15 минут. Чтобы по нажатию определённой кнопки таймер запускался, а по истечении 15 минут вызывал определённую функцию. Чем это можно сделать? `setTimeout()` в промисе?

Comment: setTimeout() с колбеком.

Comment: а что значит "на сайте"? На странице в браузере? И таймер должен отображать обратный отсчет или просто ждать и потом вызывать что-то?

Comment: @tilin на странице. API отправляет мне ссылки для перехода. Эти ссылки действительны 15 минут. После 15 минут я должен уведомить пользователя, что он должен ещё раз запросить данные, чтобы получить свежие ссылки для перехода.

Answer (score 1):

Просто запустить таймер и передать ему функцию, которая запустит оповещение пользователя через определенное время. Дополнительно можно сохранить таймер для последующей отмены, если он не понадобится

```js
const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('message');
  }, 3000);
```

для отмены до истечения таймера

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

В примере таймер на 15 секунд для наглядности. Для минут нужно умножить на 60.

```js
var timeto = 15;

function timer() {
  timeto--;
  if (timeto==0) {
    console.log('time is up!');
  } else {
    setTimeout(timer,1000);
  }
}
  
setTimeout(timer,1000); //вот это надо повесить на клик по кнопке
```

Comment: Посему не просто `setTimeout(функция,15000);`

Comment: @tilin ну можно обратный отчет на странице выводить например, хотя если это не требуется, то да так проще.